# C# System.IO.FileNotFound Exception

Tags: c#, runtime-error

This is my code. If I enter in a file that exists, everything works correctly. However, whenever I enter a file that does not exist, I get the "System.IO.FileNotFound exception error message. I'm not sure why this is. There are directions for what I have to do in the comments.

Thanks

```
 using System;
`using System.IO;

namespace IntroCS
{
class SumFile
{
/**
* Program starts here
*/
static void Main ()
{
String prompt = UIF.PromptLine ("Enter name of file to print: ");
var sr = PromptFile (prompt);
if (sr != null){
Console.WriteLine("The sum is {0}", CalcSum(sr));
}
else{
Console.WriteLine ("You give up!");
}
}
// Declare and get a StreamReader object here, from PromtpFile()
// Test if the StreamReader is null. If it is not null, calculate
// the sum of numbers in that StreamReader. Otherwise, print
// "You give up!"

static StreamReader PromptFile (string prompt)
{
String p = UIF.PromptLine ("Enter the name of file to print: ");
var reader = new StreamReader (p);
if (File.Exists (p)) {
return reader;
} else {
return null;
}
}
// Print out the prompt and read the path. Use UIF/UI function if you
// want
// Check if the path is empty string. If yes, you should return null
// If path is not empty string, your program should keep prompting
// for user input until a valid path or empty string is received
// To test if a file path is valid, use File.Exists(string path)
// function, which returns a boolean variable telling you if that
// path is valid or not.
// If the path is valid, you should return a object of StreamReader
// of that path. Otherwise, return null.

// This function take a valid StreamReader object as argument, read the
// all the lines of the file, convert them to integer, and calculate
// the sum of them
static int CalcSum(StreamReader sr)
{
int n = 0;
while (!sr.EndOfStream) {
string sVal = sr.ReadLine ().Trim ();
if (sVal.Length > 0) {
n += int.Parse (sVal);
}

}
return n;
}
// Declare a integer variable for calculating the sum.
// and initialize it to 0
// Read the entire file till the end of the stream. Use
// sr.EndOfStream to tell if you have reached the end of file
// Close the StreamReader object and return the sum of all numbers
// in that file.
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get that exception probably due to this line:

```
var reader = new StreamReader (p);
```

you execute it before checking if file exists. If you don't want that exception you should call the method which checks if file exists first.

Comment: Thank you that got rid of the error message. I didn't pick up on that.

Comment: @NickPredey: You can consider accepting the answer, if it helped you.

Comment: I will. Since I just recently made an account, I must wait.